# Non-linear Optimization

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve a non-linear optimization problem with constraints. I wrote the code (see below) to minimize sum of squared errors subject to constraints. I need to find a[1] and a[2] so that they sum up to 1. I provide a vector of initial guesses, the code runs but in the end gives me nothing but again my initial guesses. What do I do wrong? Thank you.

```
MIS <- c(0.0156, 0.0087, 0.0468)
EDF <- c(0.0008, 0.0088, 0.0059)


QFM <- data.frame(Factor1 = c(100,100,50), Factor2 = c(50,25,100))


qt.mean <- mean(EDF)

qt.sd <- sd(EDF)

z.qt <- (qnorm(EDF) - qt.mean)/qt.sd

weight <- 0.7
alpha <- -2.7
beta <- 1.0

objfun <- function(a) {

  RQL <- a[1] * QFM$Factor1 + a[2] * QFM$Factor2
  z.ql <- (RQL - mean(RQL))/sd(RQL)
  corr.factor <- cor(z.qt, z.ql)
  denom <- sqrt(weight ^ 2 + (1 - weight)^2 + 2 * corr.factor * weight * (1- weight))
  z.cs <- 1/denom * (weight * z.qt + (1-weight) * z.ql)
  z.fs <- alpha + beta * z.cs
  return(sum((MIS - pnorm(z.fs))^2))
}

eqn <- function (a) {sum(a)}

solnp(c(0.5,0.5), fun  = objfun, eqfun = eqn, eqB = 1, LB = c(0,0), UB = c(1,1))
```

```
Iter: 1 fn: 0.002509     Pars:  0.50000 0.50000
solnp--> Completed in 1 iterations
$pars
[1] 0.5 0.5

$convergence
[1] 0

$values
[1] 0.00250929 0.00250929

$lagrange
     [,1]
[1,]    0

$hessian
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

$ineqx0
NULL

$nfuneval
[1] 35

$outer.iter
[1] 1

$elapsed
Time difference of 0.02330089 secs

$vscale
[1] 0.00250929 0.60000000 1.00000000 1.00000000
```

Comment: it seems to give you the parameters `c(0.5, 0.5)` under `$pars`. What do you mean by In the end it gives you nothing?

Comment: These parameters are the initial guess, not the ones that optimize the objective function.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what your function does, but given any combination of parameters that sum up to 1, the returned value is 0.00250929

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I feel that the order of how I feed in the equations in the objective function should be different. Is it because RQL takes on the values of a which are not optimized yet? Is this why I get the initial guess as an answer? Is there any other package that I can use to check the validity of the results?

Comment: Why not optimize for one parameter `a` and set the second to `1-a`?

Comment: Florian, thank you. This is a very good observation. I just did it but it seems that the answer stays the same. I'm worried that the optimization is not doing the job.

Comment: Spadarian, thank you. I tried several combinations. Yes, the value is the same. Why is it so? Does it mean that there is no unique solution?

Comment: For valid inputs of `a` (sum to 1 and between 0 and 1) `objfun()` seems to be constant.

Comment: I've solved the problem. The problem is that all equations should be substituted inside the objective function. Otherwise, I get the initial guess as the answer. And yes, the objective function should be a number in the end. Thank you for all your valuable feedback.